# "No such file or directory" error on git commit

Tags: git

Whenever I do a commit in a git repo I get this error:

```
git commit -m test
error: could not open 'setup.cfg': No such file or directory
error: could not open 'setup.cfg': No such file or directory
Recorded preimage for 'setup.cfg'
```

What may be a reason for this? It's a basic repo with no hooks configured, etc.

Comment: What is the output of `git status` ?